# PostSharp 4 and legacy components using older versions

Tags: postsharp

For along time we've been using legacy components originally compiled using PostSharp 2. But recently we tried to upgrade our main framework to use PostSharp 4 (we want to try out some of the new features) but now every application referring to legacy components will crash. The legacy components cannot be re-compiled for legal reasons, so that is not an option for us.

Is it possible to have new code (in .Net 4.5 and using PostSharp 4.x) work together with legacy components (build on .Net 3.5 and PostSharp 2.x)?

Comment: Are you using any aspects from legacy components or are those legacy components used just as libraries?

Comment: I don't think it is using an aspect, but what it complains about is "Could not load type 'PostSharp.Reflection.MemberName'..."

Comment: The problem is that both PostSharp.dll versions are required by the application. Putting PostSharp 2 assembly to GAC or loading it from different directory (e.g. intercepting it from [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) may help.